# Problem in using muliple inner join

Tags: mysql

I have four tables :

table  p_d :

```
id   price
1     12
2     13
```

table s_d

```
id   name
1    name1
2    name2
```

table b_d

```
id    p_d_id
1       1
2       1
```

table b_d_s

```
id     b_d_id    s_d_id
1       1         1
2       1         2
```

Some info about tables :

for table b_d

column p_d_id reference p_id (id)

for table b_d_s

column b_d_id references b_d(id) , column s_d_id references s_d(id)

Now problem is that, i am unable to link all tables together using inner join .

What i need from table b_d_s:

p_d.price  where s_d_id = 1

I am not able to join table b_d_s  and  table p_d  because there is not any common column between them.

result might be

```
price 
 12
```

I also tried it at my end ,  but could not join all tables together. i used inner join .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this (in an INNER JOIN you don't necessary have to reference previous table):

```
select p_d.price
 from b_d_s inner join b_d  on b_d_s.b_d_id = b_d.id
            inner join s_d  on b_d_s.s_d_id = s_d.id
            inner join p_d  on b_d.p_d_id   = p_d.id
 where s_d.id = 1
```